# Index was out of range. Must be non negative and less than the size of the collection. in Web Method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

This is my WebMethod

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Fetch Nested Albums", EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function moveImages() As Object
    Dim FileCount As Integer = _
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Form(
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Count - 2)
End Function
```

When i try to call the web service from the .aspx page i get this error

**"Index was out of range. Must be non negative and less than the size of the collection."**

How can i access the request Object? I was not able to access the session object in the web method, so i had to add `EnableSession:=True` in the Web Method.

So is there any setting for the request Object too?

Comment: Step your code with the debugger to find whats is happening and correct your bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error is very clear. In this line the `.Count` is less that 2.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Count - 2)
```

Comment: But same code works when i execute on a button click in the page code behind.

Comment: @user1593175 well in the second case the For.Count is more than 2. Debug your code !!! Step line by line